# ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row. in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I wrote the following code in SAS in order to select the record with egrefid not equal to 3 grouped by subjid and cpevent, but was told "ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row."

```
case when (select count(egrefid) from INFMM.EDAT_EG004
           group by subjid, cpevent 
           having count(egrefid) ne 3) 
           and cpevent in ('DAY1',  'DAY29',  'DAY85') then 'triplicate' 
     else ' ' end as flag
```

I think the problem is in the count() function, but don't know how to fix it.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to find out if there are 3 ows in INFMM.EDAT_EG004 with the same subjid and cpevent as in your main query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case when is evaluated for each line. Your subquery will return all unique subjid and cpevent pairs in your INFMM.EDAT_EG004 table.

I think a join would be your best bet in this instance

```
create table egrefid_counts as
select subjid, cpevent, count(egrefid) as egrefid_count
from INFMM.EDAT_EG004
where cpeven in ('DAY1',  'DAY29',  'DAY85')
group by subjid, cpevent
;
```

Then you join that to your table on subjid and cpevent

```
select a.*, case when b.egrefid_count = 3 then 'triplicate'
                 else ' ' end as flag
from <whatever your table is> as a
left join
egrefid_count as b
on a.subjid=b.subjid and a.cpevent = b.cpevent
```